# vbulletin 4 Search doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, vbulletin

We recently upgraded to PHP 5.3 (from 5.2) and MySQL 5.1 (from 5.0) and did a database restore on vbulletin 4 forum. After these search stopped working at all.

No matter what you search, you end up on `/forum/search.php?searchid=-2139739119` with no results. ?do=getnew, ?query=your+keyword, advanced search etc. none of these work. all loads that url with negative searchid and says "Sorry - no matches. Please try some different terms."

What we tried: rebuilded the search index via command line, disabled plugin system, cleared up post cache etc. none of these worked.

What may be the cause to this problem?

Thank you very much for any input.

Answer (score 1):

1.
Please check if Zend Guard is installed. Many times it causes problems with the vBulletin search. If it's installed, try to remove it. On your php.ini file, remark this extension as comment, just like that:

```
 ;[Zend]

 ;zend_extension="/usr/local/Zend/lib/Guard-5.5.0/php-5.3.x/ZendGuardLoader.so"
```

2.
If that didn't solved the problem, try to recompile the PHP.

Comment: We dont have zend guard installed and we recently recompiled php.